# I am trying to preserve the Session cookie through multiple tests in cypress but Cypress.Cookie.preserveOnce() is not working

Tags: reactjs, testing, automated-tests, session-cookies, cypress

Am I implementing this functionality wrong or am i missing something?? I watch the application tab of the developer tools, the cookie appears after the setToken() method but despite the Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce('token_name') in the before each hook. The token is still erased in between tests.

```
  before(() => {
    cy.setToken()
  })

  beforeEach(() => {
    Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce("token_name")
    cy.visit(urlPrefix + 'applications').wait(beforeEachWait)
  })

  after(() => {
    cy.clearCookies()
  })

  it('Form should have title', () => {
    cy.contains('Edit Application').should('be.visible')
  })

  it('The Save button should be disabled until changes have been made', () => {
    cy.get('[data-cy=saveBtn]').should('be.disabled')
    cy.get('[data-cy=applicationName] input').type(' edited')
    cy.get('[data-cy=saveBtn]').should('be.enabled')
  })

  it('The cancel button redirects to the list view', () => {
    cy.get('[data-cy=cancelBtn]')
      .click()
      .wait(500)

    cy.url().then(url => {
      const applicationsTitle = url.split('#/')[1]
      expect(applicationsTitle).to.equal('applications')
    })
  })

  it('should have delete button in edit mode', () => {
    cy.get('[data-cy=deleteBtn]').should('be.visible')
  })
})
```

Comment: Perhaps `cy.clearCookies()` is the problem. If you comment that out, it might preserve only the cookies that you want, and remove the rest.

Comment: The cy.clearCookies() is in the after() hook therefore doesn't get called until all the tests have ran. The idea is that the cookies are set at the beginning of this test spec, preserved through the tests inside the spec and then cleared at the end. But currently the cookies are being cleared after each test.

Comment: There is an open issue for Cypress related to this, perhaps you could try the workarounds mentioned there https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/2952

Comment: I also had Cypress issues related to cookies - I fixed them by switching back to 3.4.1 - the cypress team is working some cookie related issues that may be affecting you

Answer (score 0):

use this one

```
Cypress.Cookies.defaults({
  preserve: 'session_id',
})
```

it will work or

```
before("cookies",() => {
cy.setCookie('session_name', 'value')
}
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 0):

**cypress latest version 10.8.0 no need to add setCookie. Add expermentalSessionAndOrigin and chromeWebSecurity in cypress.config.ts file**

```
e2e: {
        baseUrl: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        experimentalSessionAndOrigin: true,
        chromeWebSecurity: false,
      }
```